# Rails applications take a while to load after no use

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

I have a number of Rails 3.1 applications running on a local server, remote dedicated server and also on Heroku. Regardless of the applications role they always take quite some time (10 seconds?) to load the first time they are visited.

This delay also happens if an application hasn't been used for around 10 minutes.

I am trying to work out if this is a setting/configuration issue with the servers (and Heroku) or if it's something I can adjust in the Rails applications.

On our main dedicated server I am running the following versions of Rails and Ruby:

```
Rails 3.1.3

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

(If this question is better suited on ServerFault then let me know!)

Comment: What are you using on your server to run your app? Passenger? Unicorn? Thin?

Comment: Passenger, forgot to mention that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's usually the symptom when all active server processes are terminated by the web server in order to conserve resources.

Change the server configuration to keep at least one instance of your app loaded at all time. With mod_rails, for example, settings like [passenger_min_instances](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerMinInstances) and [passenger_pool_idle_time](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerPoolIdleTime) give you very granular control over this (**EDIT:** nginx version -  Apache version [here](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_resource_control_and_optimization_options)).

If that is not an option, alternatively you can send a regular HTTP request to your homepage to keep the server process alive, by running a script or using one of the many server monitoring tools like Pingdom, Alertra etc.

Comment: Thanks! Those links are a great help. If I have a server running multiple rails applications under virtual hosts on Apache, and I set the passenger min_instances to 3 would each application use one instance or would the first application reserve all three?

Comment: I think you can set the min instances per virtual host. I added a link to the apache version of the guide - it's PassengerMinInstances and PassengerPoolIdleTime there. Also look at PassengerPreStart directive to automatically fire up an instance after restart.